# Wireless isn't offline but Windows 8 Metro apps say it is when connected to VPN

Tags: windows-8-preview

In the Release Preview of Windows 8, when I connect to the internet via wireless and then connect to a VPN or another connection, Metro apps (like Messaging or Sports) complain that the wireless is offline.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What is the VPN software?

Answer (score 1):

If billc.cn is right, it would seem that a few registry changes could be in order as well as a relatively big change on the server side of things.

You'll need a web server set up on the network your VPN is connecting to which can host a file called ncsi.txt

You'll then need to change registry settings under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters\Internet`

If you can't do the above, you'll need to get the URLs under the above registry key unblocked by the VPN, presuming billc.cn is right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is  a link to the known issues with Cisco VPN's at this time and Windows 8.  It could very well be a split dns issue but I am not a network guru by any stretch of the imagination.

[latest issues in cisco 3.1 anyconnect](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/anyconnect/anyconnect31/release/notes/anyconnect31rn.html#wp1095456)!

Answer (score 0):

Please can you reword the question and provide some detail as to what the actual problem is - it becomes difficult to help diagnose a problem when we aren't given any information to work with. Also please bare in mind, Windows 8 is still in Beta (or RC I believe) so there will be bugs etc in my opinion to begin with. Why have you made this your main OS anyway?

Comment: Please delete and add as a comment to the question as it doesn't provide an answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will try to access a URL to determine network connectivity. Your VPN probably blocked that page.

If your VPN is for accessing a company network, you can disable the default route for that VPN. It's in the connection's properties, networking, TCP/IPv4, advanced, use default gateway ...

If you need the VPN for encryption/privacy, you'll probably have to contact the provider or manually setup a route to provide direct access to that page.

Comment: Can you give me a citation for Windows accessing a URL to check for connectivity? Edit: good link right on our doorstep: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/